# Electron distribution around atom when moving

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, special-relativity, wavefunction, atomic-physics

I do not have much experience on this but if an atom has some electrons around nucleus and the atom itself it is moving at some speed does that affect the distribution of electrons around?

I am presuming that the interaction between the nucleus and electrons has a  constant speed $c$. Anything I found so far is a calculation for interactions that presume an infinite speed.

As an argument I am thinking of relativistic Doppler effect that does not change proportional with $v/c$. So I am thinking that maybe the speed does affect the distribution and so that is why the difference in the emission energy.

Answer (score 1):

The speed only affects if there is an acceleration. If the atom is moving at a constant speed, you can do a galilean transformation, move with the atom, and it will be at rest.

The two simplest reasons for an atom to accelerate are collision with other atoms and bombardment.

The first one happens everytime you have a gas or a liquid. The atoms wiggle around, hitting each other. In this case, the speeds are relatively low, and the biggest effect is due to the interaction between both electron clouds. You can increase the speed by raising the temperature, but then you stop having a gas and it becomes a plasma.

The other possibility is that a particle hits the nucleus, setting it in movement. That is a classical (and very academic) example of the [sudden approximation.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14194/where-can-a-good-treatment-of-the-sudden-perturbation-approximation-be-found) In this case, the wavefunction at the beginning at the end are the same, with the only difference that the end ones are moving.

Comment: Well, at relativistic speed the atom will be observed to be compressed along it's direction of travel, but that does not affect the physics.